# Does Windows Azure App Service support .NET Framework 4.7.2?

Tags: windows, azure, azure-web-app-service, .net-framework-version, .net-4.7.2

I have a need for Windows Azure App Service platform to support .NET Framework 4.7.2.  This is because the complications with ***System.Net.Http*** is cleared up in that version.  However, I'm not sure if it's supported yet since I'm able to remove all binding redirects for System.Net.Http and run my app locally with no errors.  Unlike prior versions of .net framework, 4.7.2 is able to automatically handle redirects to the latest built-in System.Net.Http 4.2.0.0 with no issues.  But when I deploy the app to Azure App Service, the built-in handling of the binding redirects fail for some reason.  It seems to be behaving like the version of .net framework is not 4.7.2 in Azure.  In fact, as you can see from the screenshot below, the version is just listed as "4.7".  I'm assuming that this means it's version 4.7.0 and not just some generic 4.7.x? Does anybody know if there's any immediate plans to add .net framework 4.7.2 to Azure App Service?:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update**(2018/11/30):

It supports `4.7.2` currently.

[image: list of supported .NET Framework versions]

Comment: @TheDude Just follow the link to navigate to the `CMD`, first use `cd \ `, then use `cd D:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework`.

Comment: Thanks.  I found it.

Comment: Might be worth updating this answer as Azure does now support .NET Framework 4.7.2