# Project 'xxx.csproj' targets 'v4.7.2'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I have an MVC website targeting .NET 4.7.2. I also have supporting five projects that all are targetting .NET 4.7.2. The website builds and runs successfully on the local system.

However, when I deploy it on Azure using Deployment Center, the build fails. The log shows the message below.

[image]

Since all projects are targeting .NET 4.7.2, I have no clue why it is failing. Can you please nudge me on how to fix it?

Comment: MSBuild 15.0 (see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/what-s-new-in-msbuild-15-0?view=vs-2022) is Core.  You are using Net 4.7.2.   Make sure your AZURE settings is using Net 4.7.2 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433805/does-windows-azure-app-service-support-net-framework-4-7-2

Answer (score 0):

The [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63626993/1041457) along with [MS article MSBuild target framework and target platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-target-framework-and-target-platform?view=vs-2022) helped in resolving the issue.

The specific helpful part from the article shares:

> The target framework is specified in the TargetFrameworkVersion property in the project file. You can change the target framework for a project by using the project property pages in the Visual Studio integrated development environment (IDE). For more information, see How to: Target a version of the .NET Framework. The available values for TargetFrameworkVersion are v2.0, v3.0, v4.0, v3.5, v4.5.2, v4.6, v4.6.1, v4.6.2, v4.7, v4.7.1, v4.7.2, and v4.8.

In my case I was having file `Directory.Build.props` in root directory of the solution. However, I was using `TargetFramework` instead of `TargetFrameworkVersion` with value `v4.7.2`. I believe it was the *culprit* that was causing the issue.

So, I fixed it by using `TargetFrameworkVersion` with same value `v4.7.2`. The below is the content of `Directory.Build.props` file for sample.

[image: Directory.Build.props file content]